# How to clear forms according to two cases?

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched and tried many 'solutions' that I found around but none worked for me. So I have two forms on my page, `mainForm` & `secondaryFrom`. I have set up the code in JS so that each of these forms' displays properties act to be `block` or `none` and vice versa, according to statements and one will be shown at a time. However, if the shown form has values, they get mixed with the other form's values (such name and email inputs values) and at the submit, I receive both forms' values. So I want to clear the other, hidden, form's values if it gets `none` as display property, and vice versa, each time their display is changed. Hopefully I was able to explain it well enough.

HTML:

```
<form id="mainForm">
  <!-- inputs and labels. All inputs have 'main-input' classes -->
</form>
<form id="secondaryForm">
  <!-- inputs and labels. All inputs have 'secondary-input' classes -->
</form>
```

This runs on button click:

JS:

```
const mainForm = document.getElementById('mainForm');
const secondaryForm = document.getElementById('secondaryForm');
    if (mainForm.style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementsByClassName('secondary-input').value = '';

        }
    if (secondaryForm.style.display == 'block') {
            document.getElementsByClassName('main-input').value = '';
    }
```

I also tried reset() method but still not working. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

document.getElementsByClassName('secondary-input') method returns a collection of  elements.

You should iterate the collection and set the value individually

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('main-input');
for (var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
    elements[index].value='';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code:  getElementsByClassName returns a collection.  If you are sold on the idea of using that getElementsByClassName logic, you will need to iterate through the collection to clear values.  Otherwise, you will need to reference each collection item by index.  Of course you could always switch to getElementById.

Below will work assuming you had 2 inputs for 'main-input' and two inputs for 'secondary'input'.  Apologies for not taking the time to write a for loop or provide complete code to show you.  I think you will see what I mean if you plug this in and read up on getElementByClassName.  Still figuring out how post good code examples in SO editor.  Cheers!

```
  document.getElementsByClassName('main-input')[0].value = '';
  document.getElementsByClassName('main-input')[1].value = '';
  document.getElementsByClassName('secondary-input')[0].value = '';
  document.getElementsByClassName('secondary-input')[1].value = '';
```